# Permission Denied on Arduino serial stream

Tags: arduino, serial

I'm collecting data with a serial stream from an Arduino microcontroller.

I'm using Cygwin my recording sometimes randomly stops and I get a 'tee read error: Permission Denied' message.

The way I'm doing the recording is that I navigate to the folder I want to store the data file and I enter in a command like

```
tee </dev/ttyS2 Data.txt
```

However, in the middle of recording, the recording stops and I get a 'tee read error: Permission Denied' error. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it? It's not like I suddenly have lost my permission to the folder I'm saving my data in.

Comment: This question doesn't deal with electronics design.

Comment: As an embedded toolchain/debug issue, it is on topic.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use Cygwin. Seriously. I've been trying it for the last 15 years, and it just isn't a reliable way to write working software. The translation layer is just too fragile. I can't say for *sure* that this is a Cygwin problem, but that's the most obvious problem in the setup you descibe.

If you need UNIX, use Linux or BSD.

If you need Windows, use Visual Studio Express, which is free, and use the Win32 or .NET APIs.

And this sounds a lot like a software question, rather than an electronics question!

Comment: An intermediate alternative is using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) on your Windows box, then install a Linux VM in there and route Arduino's USB to the VM (there is a configuration menu for that in VBox). Then do your magic in the Linux VM (Ubuntu *Server* is a great command line only distribution, set it up so you can access it with [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)). I agree Cygwin is very useful for many tasks but it has its limits. You are probably hitting a buffer limit.